# Use of Angular with Jquery

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript

I am new to Angular 8 and working on a project with a team. There is some code which I can't understand.It is very helpful to me if anyone will explain it.I shall be very thankful to that person who explains this code to me. In this code, are we using Jquery with angular?

```js
fetch(state : State)
  {
    const queryStr = `?skip=${state.skip}&take=${state.take}&count=true&pageSize=${this.pageSize}&page=${state.skip/this.pageSize + 1}`;
    return this.http
        .get(`${this.url}?${queryStr}`)
        .pipe(
            map(response => (<GridDataResult>{
                data: response['Data'],
                total: parseInt(response['Total'])
            }))
            ,
            tap(() => false)
        );
  }

  public GetList(state: DataSourceRequestState): Observable<DataResult> {
    const queryStr = `${toDataSourceRequestString(state)}`; // Serialize the state
    const hasGroups = state.group && state.group.length;

    return this.http
        .get(`${this.url}?${queryStr}`) // Send the state to the server
        .map(response => (<GridDataResult>{
          data: response['Data'],
          total: parseInt(response['Total'])
      }))
        // .map(({data, total/*, aggregateResults*/} : GridDataResult) => // Process the response
        //     (<GridDataResult>{
        //         // If there are groups, convert them to a compatible format
        //         test : console.log(total ),

        //         data: hasGroups ? translateDataSourceResultGroups(data) : data,
        //         total: total,
        //         // Convert the aggregates if such exist
        //         //aggregateResult: translateAggregateResults(aggregateResults)
        //     })
        // )
}
```

Comment: All of the dollar symbols are being used for string interpolation, nothing to do with jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Jquery here, syntax `${this.url}?${queryStr}` is interpolation.

I example

```
url = 'home/index';

queryStr = 'id=1';
```

With interpolation `${this.url}?${queryStr}` => `'home/index?id=1'`

If you use concat string way, you can `url + "?" + queryStr`

You can refer more at [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: syntax ${this.url}?${queryStr} is interpolation.   Please give me some explanation links of this type syntax